# ngAnimate 1.4.7 unit test not calling animation functions

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, coffeescript, ng-animate

I've been working from [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/angularjs-testing-tips-bootstrap-blocks-routes-events-animations/) and have Googled ad nauseum, but I can't seem to get what appears to be a trivial `ngAnimate` unit test running.

I have `ngAnimate` working well in the app. All Angular core libraries are version 1.4.7.

**Module**

```
angular.module 'MyAnimation', [ 'ngAnimate' ]
  .animation '.added-class', ->
    addClass: (element, className, done) ->
      console.log 'add class triggered'
      element.css 'opacity', '0.5'
      done()
```

**Test**

```
describe 'MyAnimation', ->
  beforeEach -> module 'ngAnimate'
  beforeEach -> module 'ngAnimateMock'
  beforeEach -> module 'MyAnimation'

  it 'animates', -> inject ($animate, $rootScope, $rootElement) ->
    $animate.enabled(true)
    divElement = angular.element '<div>my div</div>'

    # Kick off initial digest loop in which no animations are run.
    $rootScope.$digest()

    # Trigger animation.
    $animate.addClass divElement, 'added-class'
    $rootScope.$digest()

    # Tried this, doesn't seem to do anything.
    # $animate.flush()

    # Results in AssertionError: expected '' to equal '0.5'
    expect(divElement.css('opacity')).to.eq '0.5'
```

I'm sure that the module is being included in the test, but triggering `$animate.enter` doesn't even get me my `log` output.

I've tried this with other `$animate` functions as well and am getting nowhere. Help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some serious digging into Angular's source code, it appears that the culprit is the internal check [`areAnimationsAllowed`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/bfad2a4f4ae71cfead61c112b0d2ab1fcadd39ee/src/ngAnimate/animateQueue.js#L533) which Angular uses to determine whether to abort the animation early. Among other things, it **checks that the node being animated is a descendant of the `$rootElement` and the document body.**

You have two options here.

1. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GhQFwIDJ9HEEQbNgLmGY?p=preview). **Attach the node you are animating to `$rootElement` and attach the `$rootElement` to the body**. The latter is necessary because `ngMock` actually stubs `$rootElement` with a detached `<div>` node held in memory. *Example:*

```js
var element, body, root;
beforeEach(module('ngAnimate', 'ngAnimateMock', 'MyAnimation'));
beforeEach(inject(function ($animate, $document, $rootElement, $rootScope) {
  // enable animations globally
  $animate.enabled(true);

  // create a node to be animated and inject it into the DOM
  element = angular.element('<div></div>');
  root = $rootElement.append(element)[0];
  body = $document[0].body;
  body.appendChild(root);

  // trigger initial digest
  $rootScope.$digest();
}));
afterEach(function () {
  // clean up
  body.removeChild(root);
});
```

2. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hXbzZybASa7NxdzZdSzr?p=preview). Do not test your animation using `$animate.addClass`, but instead **use the lower-level `$$animateJs` service**. Angular uses it [inside their own tests](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d077966ff1ac18262f4615ff1a533db24d4432a7/test/ngAnimate/animateJsSpec.js#L212), I assume to bypass the above check. *Example:*

```js
it('should animate', inject(function ($animate, $$animateJs) {
  // trigger animation
  $$animateJs(element, 'addClass', {
    addClass: 'added-class'
  }).start();
  $animate.flush();
}));
```

If you run the Plunkers and check the console, you should see your "addClass triggered" message. I have also added a couple assertions.

Both solutions are hacky and undocumented, and both become more involved if your `addClass` animation does something asynchronous (which I assume it will). Unfortunately, I cannot find a better way to test JS animations. In the past I've actually ignored animation code from coverage because it's so difficult to test.