# unit test template in angular modal service ($uibModal)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, modal-dialog, karma-jasmine

I have a very simple service.show() which basically calls $uibModal with some configuration and returns the modal instance

```
function modalService($uibModal) {
  return {
    show(message) {
      return $uibModal.open({
        bindToController: true,
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        template: "<div id='message'>{{$ctrl.message}}</div>",
        controller: [function() {
          this.message = message;
        }]
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to write a test to validate actual modal and if it contains expected message. Something like this:

```
it('should show correct message', (done) => {
    modal = modalService.show('hello');
    modal.rendered.then(()=> {
      expect($('#message').text()).toBe('hello');
      done()
    });
  });
```

but `rendered` promise is never resolved. I can do some workaround like wrapping `expect` into `$timeout` and do `$timeout.flush()` but not sure if this is correct way and even in this way I still can't do a cleanup (`afterEach`) to close the modal and be ready to test another message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way will be to open the modal window look for the message and close it and as bootstrap is using `ngAnimate` for the animation we will have to include `ngAnimateMock` module to flush the pending animation.

Check the below code for the solution:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.factory('modalService', ['$uibModal', function($uibModal) {
  return {
    show(message) {
      return $uibModal.open({
        bindToController: true,
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        template: '<div id="message">{{$ctrl.message}}</div>',
        controller: [function() {
          this.message = message;
        }]
      });
    }
  }
}]);

describe('modalService service', function() {
  describe('modalService', function() {
    var modalService;
    var $rootScope;
    var $animate;

    beforeEach(function() {
      module('ngAnimateMock')
      module('uib/template/modal/window.html')
      module('myApp');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _modalService_, _$animate_) {
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      modalService = _modalService_;
      $animate = _$animate_;
    }));

    it('should open the dialog with the correct message', () => {
      var modal = modalService.show('hello');

      $rootScope.$digest();
      // Finish the animation.
      $animate.flush();

      expect($('#message').text()).toEqual('hello');

      // Close the dialog.
      modal.close();

      $rootScope.$digest();
      // Finish the animation.
      $animate.flush();
    });

    it('again should show the correct message', () => {
      var modal = modalService.show('new message');

      $rootScope.$digest();
      // Finish the animation.
      $animate.flush();

      expect($('#message').text()).toEqual('new message');

      // Close the dialog.
      modal.close();

      $rootScope.$digest();
      // Finish the animation.
      $animate.flush();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- because we are testing our controller and not running we don't need a controller or even a module -->
  <!-- so there is no ng-app or ng-controller in the markup -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine.css">

  <!-- the order that these files load is critical, think twice before changing -->
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/boot.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-mocks.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <h2>Finished jasmine-unit-test</h2>

</body>
```

Comment: The first test passes, but the second one fails with message `Expected 'new messagehello' to equal 'new message'.` The `modal.close()` doesn't remove modal from dom. Do you have a clue why might it happen?

Comment: and why do I need module('uib/template/modal/window.html') ?

Comment: The code snippet that I've provided, both the test are passing. Can you provide codepen/jsfiddle etc, so that I can look into that. And regarding your other question, you will need to include `module('uib/template/modal/window.html')` because when you make `$uibModal.open()` call internally it fetches the template 'window.html'.

Comment: if you change from id to class it finds both. So they are both in a dom but id selects first and ignores the other one. With `#message` works for me as well but if i change to `.message` it finds the previous value as well

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle link, and I've changed the code as you mentioned from `id` to `class`, but it works for me. https://jsfiddle.net/gauravmahto/dj3fbztu/

Comment: The problem for me was with $animate service, I think there is some transition time between closing/opening modal so at that point both are present in the dom. if I do $animation.enabled(false) in beforeEach it works (or if I don't use `$animation.flush()` at all). But I still don't get why `modal.rendered.then(smth)` is never called in the test? It is calling  `modal.opened.then(smth)` though. I updated you fiddle with some alert on modal.rendered but it is never called. https://jsfiddle.net/dj3fbztu/2/ Do  you have a clue why it is not called? and is it expected behaviour?

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle; https://jsfiddle.net/gauravmahto/dj3fbztu/3/
And in this fiddle I'm not disabling the animation, instead, I manually flush the animation as I think internally it is doing some extra work and to understand that I'll have to dig deeper. But the main thing here is if you change the assertion at line no#44 to make it fail, you will see that the test actually fails and that confirms that the promise returned by calling `modal.rendered` was indeed resolved and thus calling the chained function.

Comment: This could be unrelated, but anyways here is an interesting topic about bootstrap testing tips https://www.sitepoint.com/angularjs-testing-tips-bootstrap-blocks-routes-events-animations/ . Another STOF answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405666/nganimate-1-4-7-unit-test-not-calling-animation-functions?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Thanks mate. That was really helpful

Comment: Glad to help :)